# How do I retrieve the id of the selected option from a bootstrap dropDown list?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have built this simple dropDown list:
[image]
Here's its html definition:

```
<select class="form-control" id='0' (change)="retrieveValue($event.target)">
      <option id='0'>{{ genericSpecific[params.node.id][0] }}</option>
      <option id='1'>{{ genericSpecific[params.node.id][1] }}</option>
    </select>
```

For retrieving the value:

```
  updateChosenValue(event) {
 console.log(event.value)}
```

But, I couldn't find a way to retrieve the id.
Any help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. this may help you to understand the logic.. but still you'll have to make this compatible to your angular code.

```html
    <select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('id'));" name="myname" class="myclass"> 
        <option id="1" value="hi">click1</option>
        <option id="2" value="hello">click2</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select class="form-control" id='0' (change)="retrieveValue($event.target)">
  <option  id='0' value='0'>{{ genericSpecific[params.node.id][0] }}</option>
  <option id='1' value='1'>{{ genericSpecific[params.node.id][1] }}</option>
</select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vo9cuj

Answer (score 0):

Change HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id='0' (change)="retrieveValue($event)">
      <option id='0'>A</option>
      <option id='1'>B</option>
    </select>
```

Update ts

```
retrieveValue(event) {
     const selectEl = event.target;
     const val = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].getAttribute('id');
     console.log(val)
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfb45a